# Can't get shouldComponenUpdate() to work in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Does `shouldComponentUpdate` not work in React Native, or am I missing something? I'm just trying to log the arguments so that I can compare but it's not even being logged. All I see when I run the JS is "######### render called".

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log("######### shouldComponentUpdate called");
        console.log(nextProps);
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        console.log("######### render called");
        return <SomeJSX>
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: its because you never call setState

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate works as expected. A higher order component wrapping my component is causing my re-rendering issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` is part of `update` phase, so you have to change either `props` or `state` to get the desired output. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)